# Align ul and span to the extreme right of a enclosing div using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have used a span element and a reactstrap Nav element in my React component. In the browser the html elements look like this

```
<div class="alignRegFSBackContentsInSingleRow">
    <span class="angleLeftNavigateBack"/>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="sc-bdVaJa hBLssO nav-link" id="wizardPreviousButton">Basic Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav" id="nextButtonNav">
        <li class="nav-item" id="nextButtonNavItem">
            <a class="sc-bwzfXH bDoCBt nav-link" id="wizardNextButton">Collateral Details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="angleRightNavigateBack"/>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS of the container div

```
.alignRegFSBackContentsInSingleRow{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    max-width: fit-content;
    height: 20px;
}
```

CSS pf the two arrow elements for which I am using the spans

```
.angleLeftNavigateBack::after{
    content: "\f104";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: medium;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.angleRightNavigateBack::after{
    content: "\f105";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: medium;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

My requirement is to align the second set of  and  elements to the extreme right inside the container div. I have tried using **margin-left: auto** on the span and ul. Also tried **justify-content: space-between** for the container div. Also tried **float:right** on the ul and span but nothing works

Please help. I am definitely missing something silly here

Codesandbox Link here : https://2f095.csb.app/

[image: Image for more details]

Comment: have you tried using ```display:flex; width:100%``` or use ```display:flex; flex-grow:1``` properties? If possible please create some working example over ```stackbltiz``` or any other suitable portal and share the link. Will be helpful for us to understand it more clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for so not going to provide an answer but one thing that messes up your HTML straight away is that you can't close span elements like that. Use <span></span>. Other thing I would recommend looking at is self-align CSS attribute.

Comment: I added the style margin-left: 'auto' to the second span with css class angleRightNavigateBack above and changed the max-width to 100% in the alignRegFSBackContentsInSingleRow css class and it got aligned to the right corner. I think the issue is with the second <ul/> only now. I assigned  margin-left: 'auto' to the ul but it does not align properly to the right

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena here is the codesandbox link https://2f095.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your sandbox and finally noticed that you were using the nav component twice in your div.  I've never tried to use two navs within the same div before but I would assume that bootstrap is applying styling to them that makes it difficult to accomplish what you are trying to do.  By eliminating one of the nav components and including both nav-items within the same nav, I believe I was able to apply styling to the overall nav element to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
<div className="alignAmendFSBackContentsInSingleRow">
  <span className="angleLeftNavigateBack"></span>
  <Nav className="navFormatting">
    <NavItem>
      <StyledLink
        id="wizardPreviousButton"
        onClick={() => {
          this.previousButtonClick();
        }}
      >
        Back
      </StyledLink>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem id="nextButtonNavItem">
      <NextButtonStyledLink id="wizardNextButton">
        Next
      </NextButtonStyledLink>
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
  <span
    style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
    className="angleRightNavigateBack"
  ></span>
</div>
```

They styling in the styles.css file is below:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navFormatting {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.angleRightNavigateBack::after {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: medium;
}

.angleLeftNavigateBack::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: medium;
}

.alignAmendFSBackContentsInSingleRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

There are likely other methods out there that could accomplish what you are trying to do with two nav components but I hope this solution helps provide some guidance.

[Image of modified code output on Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4B6H.png)

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 points for this one. Resolved my issue

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help out!

Answer (score 1):

By keeping all your code as it is, I have just modified your CSS a bit.
Have just added `flex` properties on `.navFormatting` class
Below is the changed code.

```
  .navFormatting li {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
 }
.navFormatting li:first-child {
    justify-content: flex-start;
 }
.navFormatting li:last-child {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Nav, NavItem } from "reactstrap";
import StyledLink from "./styledLink";
import NextButtonStyledLink from "./nextbuttonstyledLink";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="alignAmendFSBackContentsInSingleRow">
      <span className="angleLeftNavigateBack"></span>
      <Nav className="navFormatting">
        <NavItem>
          <StyledLink
            id="wizardPreviousButton"
            onClick={() => {
              this.previousButtonClick();
            }}
          >
            Back
          </StyledLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem id="nextButtonNavItem">
          <NextButtonStyledLink id="wizardNextButton">
            Next
          </NextButtonStyledLink>
        </NavItem>
      </Nav>
      <span
        style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
        className="angleRightNavigateBack"
      ></span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.navFormatting {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin:8px;
  padding:0;
}
.navFormatting li {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.navFormatting li:first-child {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.navFormatting li:last-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.angleRightNavigateBack::after {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: medium;
}

.angleLeftNavigateBack::after {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: medium;
}

.alignAmendFSBackContentsInSingleRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to adjust the position of the unordered lists:

```
.nav{
   padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Hey all, any thoughts?